# iOS Today Widget Seems to Install only on iOS 8.3 Devices, not 8.1 or 8.2

Tags: xcode6, ios8-today-widget

Just created a Today Widget and all seems to be good (on ios 8.3) devices.  It installs and runs fine from XCODE 6.3.1.  But on iOS 8.2 or 8.1 devices, the Today Widget does not install / run even though XCODE says it is running.

If a breakpoint is put on ViewDidLoad it never gets hit.  Will try and do some digging in the logs, but so far nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make sure that the deployment platform for the Today Widget is set to 8.0.  It was created and set to 8.3 and XCODE did not have any error messages when trying to run on 8.1, 8.2, etc.